# Can I travel back to USA from Schengen area within 90 days of my H1B visa expiry?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, schengen-visas, h1b-visas

I got Schengen visa valid from Sep 7 - Oct 17.

My H1B Visa expires on Dec 31st.

In order to meet the rule that my departure date from Schengen area should be beyond 90 days of my H1B visa expiry, I should return to USA by Sep 30th.

But can I travel back to USA on Oct 16.

Will there be any problem (immigration in USA or while leaving Schengen area) even if I have visa until oct17th.

Comment: What rule is this that requires you to leave Schengen according to the date of your H1B expiry? The two are unrelated, AFAIK.

Comment: @Traveller that sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The rule when applying for a Schengen visa is typically that your travel documents (passport, residence permit etc) must be valid for a given period of time after the date you propose to exit the Schengen zone. If you already have your visa, you can use it within the number of days/validity period granted. Schengen authorities will really only care that you observe the terms of your visa and exit on or before the visa validity date. US immigration will only care that you have the right travel documents to enter the US.

Comment: Thank you Traveller for your answer..that helps me.